# Flipping of Order Sequence

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, list, hashmap

Problem Description:-

I've two files. Each file has **order_number**, which is a random alphanumeric string and they are unique to each other. 
Both files contain same number of **order_number** and if one **order_number** is in one file then it must be present in another file regardless of the position it is in the files.

Below are the example flies:

- File1

  ```
  abc123
  def234
  skd109
  djkk09
  nknk323
  ```
- File2

  ```
  skd109
  def234
  abc123
  nknk323
  djkk09
  ```

Now I've to write a program which takes **file1** as a reference and see which orders are flipped relatively according to the position in **file2**.

For instance consider above two files. Order_number **abc123** in file1 is at position 1 but in file2 its at position 3 and it is coming after two order_number ( **skd109 and def234** ) respectively in file2.

Order_number **def234** is coming after **skd109** in file2.

And order_number djkk09 and nknk323 are flipped.

**The output of my program should look like this:**

```
    abc123 is flipped by 2 ( +ve sign because it came after )
    def234 is flipped by 0
    skd109 is flipped by -2 ( -ve sign because it came before )
    djkk09 is flipped by 1
    nknk323 is flipped by -1
```

Note: Each file has more than million record in them. So the solution should be efficient.

**Below is my code:-**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Matching {
    public static void main( String args[]) throws IOException{

    /* Variable Declaration */  
    int ordersFlipped = 0;
    int ordersNotFlipped = 0;
    String lineFile1 = null;
    String lineFile2 = null;
    int indexFile2 = 0;
    int indexFile1 = 0;


    /*      Scanner     */  
    BufferedReader file2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FlipAnalysis/file2"));
    BufferedReader file1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1"));

    /*      File Creation       */
    File file = new File("Result");

    /*      Objects to write into the files     */
    PrintWriter outputResult = new PrintWriter(file);

   /* Hash Map*/
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    while ((lineFile2 = file2.readLine()) != null){
        indexFile2++;
        map.put(line,indexMe);
    }

    System.out.println("Map is ready. Now performing Matching.");

    while (( lineFile1 = inputFile1.readLine()) != null){
        indexFile1++;
        if(map.containsKey(lineFile1)){

            if(((indexFile - map.get(lineFile1))!= 0) 
                {
                    outputResult.println(lineFile1 + " Flipped by: " +(indexFile - map.get(lineFile1));
orderFlipped++;
}

                    else{
                        outputResult.println( lineFile1 + " Flipped by: 0" );
ordersNotFlipped++;

                    }
            }
        }





    outputResult.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------\n"+ "Total Order Flipped: " +ordersFlipped);
    outputResult.println("\nOrder Not Flipped: " +ordersNotFlipped);
    outputResult.println("\nTotal Number of Orders: " + (ordersFlipped + ordersNotFlipped));
    System.out.println("Done!!");
    inputFile2.close();
    inputFile1.close();
    outputResult.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a site to outsource your homework or work assignment.  Put some effort into it, and ask a question if you need specific help.

Comment: I've certainly put some effort into it.  Below is my logic:- 1. Created the HashMap to store file2.  Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, DataMe>();
 
 while ((lineMe = inputMe.readLine()) != null){
  indexMe++;
  map.put(lineMe,intexMe++);
 }  2. Reading the file1 line by line . And Comparing the index number to get the flips. while (( lineOuch = inputOuch.readLine()) != null){
  }

Comment: @OP, good to hear.  Now can you edit your original post with that code, both so that it;s more readable, and so that others see it.  You'll get better help that way.

Comment: Shouldn't output be: `abc123 is flipped by 2`, `def234 is flipped by 0`, `skd109 is flipped by -2`, `djkk09 is flipped by 1`, `nknk323 is flipped by -1`? If not, I don't understand your logic.

Comment: Yes you are right...!!

Answer (score 0):

Assumes you hava JDK 7 or higher.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Creating hashmap...");

    HashMap<String, Integer> newOrderNumberPositionMap = new HashMap<>();

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\test\\file2.txt"), 4096)) {
        String orderNumber;
        int lineNo = 1;
        while ((orderNumber = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            newOrderNumberPositionMap.put(orderNumber, lineNo);
            lineNo++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Map is ready. Now performing matching and writing result...");

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\test\\file1.txt"), 4096);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("d:\\test\\result.txt"), 4096)) {
        int ordersFlipped = 0;
        String orderNumber;
        int lineNo = 1;
        while ((orderNumber = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            int newLineNo = newOrderNumberPositionMap.get(orderNumber);

            writer.write(orderNumber);
            writer.write(" is flipped by ");
            writer.write(String.valueOf(newLineNo - lineNo));
            writer.newLine();

            if ((newLineNo - lineNo) != 0) {
                ordersFlipped++;
            }

            lineNo++;
        }

        writer.newLine();
        writer.write("--------------------------------------------------------------");
        writer.newLine();

        writer.write("Orders Flipped: ");
        writer.write(String.valueOf(ordersFlipped));
        writer.newLine();

        writer.write("Orders Not Flipped: ");
        writer.write(String.valueOf(newOrderNumberPositionMap.size() - ordersFlipped));
        writer.newLine();

        writer.write("Total Number of Orders: ");
        writer.write(String.valueOf(newOrderNumberPositionMap.size()));
        writer.newLine();

    }

    System.out.println("Done.");
}
```